# What are the equations for a 2D projection of the distortion induced by a cylindrical lens?

Tags: lenses

Imagine you have a cylindrical lens of power $C$ and of angle $\theta$ relative to some neutral 0 axis.

I want to know, if you took a normal 2D image and shown it through that lens, what would the distortion look like? For example, suppose we shined a projector through that lens.

What would the equations be to distort the points? Is this trivial to figure out? if so, how do you do it? If not, why?

Comment: Are you replacing the ordinary spherical lens of the projector with a cylindrical lens with the same focal length, or are you putting a cylindrical lens next to the spherical lens? In the former case, the image will be completely out of focus in one direction, as if you had no lens. The results of the latter case are illustrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaD9rAef-bI). Real human vision with astigmatism isn't quite as simple as this video would make it seem because the human eye can accommodate to minimize blur.

Comment: The second and the video is great but I wanted something mathematical more so as I'm trying to understand specifically how this would affect say the way and image would appear. I want something where I can plug in different angles and observe the impact on the image